# How to print line number in new column when patterns from first file occur in another file?

Tags: shell, awk, grep, text-processing

I am new here so sorry if my message is not properly formatted.

I have several files, file1 including only the reference patterns and the others including diverse information. I would like to recover the line number, in new columns, where the pattern of file1 occur in each other file. If possible, I would like the corresponding file name to be included in header.

Finally, I would like all lines where a value is missing to be removed from the final output.

file1:

```
Entry
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
xyz
```

file2:

```
line1: red|31000|ghi
line2: purple|25640|mno
line3: yellow|9560|abc
line12: blue|2630|def
line120: white|1|xyz
```

file3:

```
line1: blue|144009|def
line2: red|100000|ghi
line3: purple|60500|mno
line52: white|2|xyz
```

Expected final output:

```
Entry|file2|file3
def|12|1
ghi|1|2
mno|2|3
xyz|120|52
```

I guess there is a solution using awk, but I am not very could to deal with it on my own (sorry). I have tried to use grep which I know ca n print the line number and and compare several files but it is probably not the good option since it printed the second file as it was initially.

```
grep -Fnf file1 file2 > output
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, thank you for your comment. Is there a simple way to edit my post? Sorry again, I am new here and not yet familiar with the practical usage of the forum.

Comment: To the left of your user Id, you can see the links for "share", "edit" and flag". Click "edit"

Comment: I don't feel it is doable with grep. Try to write a python/perl/awk script for the purpose.

Comment: @serpantinAL it's better but do the `line12:` etc. values you show in your input files REALLY exist in those files or are you trying to tell us that the rest of the text exists at line 12? If the former, fine, if the latter then fix that so the input files in your question show exactly and only your actual input. Again - we need you to provide input files that we can copy/paste to test with. Either YOU have to provide input files for us to test with or everyone reading your question has to create their own input files to test with. Guess which approach is like to produce the most/best answers!

Comment: Also, include cases where `abc`, etc. appear in the first column of file2 and file3 and where `abcdef` appears in the 3rd column so we can see if you're looking to match anywhere on the line, only in 1 column, only full fields or partial fields, etc. Also if your files can contain regexp metacharacters then include the handling of those in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU join, GNU sort, GNU awk and bash:

```
join -t '|' -j 4 <(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {print NR,$0}' file2 | sort -t '|' -k4) <(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {print NR,$0}' file3 | sort -t '|' -k4) -o 1.4,1.1,2.1
```

Comment: Great! many thanks, it is what I expected. My input is a little bit different but I was able to manage perfectly with this code! Thank you again @Cyrus !

Comment: Just an additional question. What if I have more than 2 files?

Comment: From my point of view this won't work with join and without loops. Then it's time for a pure awk program.